# Help understanding passage about maximum of normal hermitian functionals

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

In the proof of the above theorem, I was confused about the following statement:

> Since $\rho$ takes its maximum on $(\mathscr{R}_h)_1$, there is an extreme point...

Can anyone explain to me how to conclude that $\rho$ takes its maximum at an extreme point?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly it is that you want to know? The passage does not imply that $\rho$ takes its maximum at an extreme point.

Comment: How to conclude that there is an extreme point at which $\rho$ takes the value $\|\rho\|$ .

Comment: I mean how to use that fact that $\rho$ takes its maximum on $(\mathscr{R}_h)_1$ to conclude  that there is an extreme point of $(\mathscr{R}_h)_1$ at which $\rho$ takes the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\R{\mathscr R}$

Since you are reading Kadison-Ringrose, I'll quote from that book.

On $(\R)_1$, the functional $\rho$ is bounded by $\|\rho\|$. By definition of the norm, this means that there exists a sequence $\{A_n\}\subset(\R)_1$ with $|\rho(A_n)|\to\|\rho\|$. Because $(\R)_1$ is weakly compact, there exists a subnet $\{A_{n_j}\}$ and $A\in(\R)_1$ such that $A_{n_j}\to A$ weakly. As $\rho$ is normal,
$$
|\rho(A)|=\lim_j|\rho(A_{n_j})|=\|\rho\|.
$$
Write $\rho(A)=|\rho(A)|\,e^{i\theta}$. Then
$$
\rho(e^{-i\theta}A)=|\rho(A)|=\|\rho\|. 
$$
We now remane $e^{-i\theta}A$ to $A$ and we have $\rho(A)=\|\rho\|$. As we  have $\rho(A^*)=\overline{\rho(A)}=\overline{\|\rho\|}=\|\rho\|$,
$$
\rho\Big(\tfrac12(A+A^*)\Big)=\|\rho\|.
$$
So we may replace $A$ with $\tfrac12(A+A^*)$ and thus assume that $A$ is selfadjoint.

Now apply Corollary 1.4.4 to obtain an extreme point $A$ in $(\R_h)_1$ with $\rho(A)=\|\rho\|$.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question. According to the theorem, we only know that $\rho$ attains its maximum at an extreme point $2E-I$ of $(\mathscr{R}_h)_1$. Can we construct the projection $E$ directly through $\rho$?

Comment: Not sure what you want. The proof of 7.4.6 is a page long.

Comment: I mean whether the extreme point at which $\rho$ takes its maximum is unique?

Comment: This is the first time the word *unique* appears since you posted the question. Where did you get that?